# How to add custom app to Timeline

Tags: timeline

I have designed a small (403 pixels wide) informational dashboard (jQuery, HTML) and subscription app. I wish to be able for the user to install the app and place it onto their TimeLine, however I am clueless as to how to do that.

Can someone explain to me how that is achieved? I see how users can put fluffy stuff on the TimeLine (pics, links, etc.) but how to you get an actual app in there?

My app is no wider than the pics that my (potential) customers display on their Timeline.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean to post content from your app or do you want to actually display your application in the timeline?

Comment: Actually display my application in the timeline. I have designed all the UI to conform to 403px and runs totally in jquery/HTML5 and I want to have it sitting on the timeline just like all that other fluffy stuff.

Comment: Are we talking about Facebook Timeline here? Twitter timeline? Or some other timeline?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that your approach is wrong and you can't display an application on Facebook's Timeline per se.

Your App can post content (text, images, etc) to a user's timeline and it can also have a [dedicated section (collection)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/#customprompt) on Timeline (you need to explicitly ask the user to add it after they activate your application, it's not automatic).

A prerequisite to having sections is that your App has [custom actions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-action-types/) and a custom collection (see detailed description in the later link), which can be displayed in one of the three custom collection types supported by Facebook - List, Gallery or Map.

Note that your custom collection will require a review.

Unfortunately it seems you will have to rework your application to fit the Facebook framework.

Comment: ılǝ, is that mean that I can't create custom section via Facebook app in personal profile timeline? This is my original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532698/how-to-create-facebook-app-that-has-own-custom-section-tab-badge-block-box-in